# merging of Netcdf files

Tags: csv, metadata, netcdf

I have around 500 netcdf(.nc) files.I need to combine all of them to a single file.I am new to programming and I don't have sufficient knowledge in merging these files.Can anybody please explain how we can merge these files and extract to a csv file or excel sheet.Which function we can use for merging of files.Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: You can combine variables in netCDF files, if they have the same dimensions. This is best done if the variables have an unlimited dimension, which you can use to append all the files. But you can also add a new dimension and join the files there. In any case, the result will depend on your data structures, so no generic answer is possible.

Answer (score 1):

NCO's ncecat can combine any number of netCDF files together with

```
ncecat in1.nc in2.nc ... inN.nc out.nc
ncecat in*.nc out.nc
```

Switches and other options are described in the [documentation](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncecat).

Answer (score 0):

you can merge files which have different variables using

```
cdo merge in1.nc in2.nc ... inN.nc out.nc
```

or if they are the same variable for different time periods, you can merge along the time axis with

```
cdo mergetime in1.nc in2.nc ... inN.nc out.nc
```

Note though, that in order to do this CDO has to have all input files open at once, and on some systems, the limit on the number of open files is 256. So in order to merge 500 files you would need to do it in 2 or more steps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this shell script to get merge the 500 netcdf files you have.  It is a rough idea of what you could do:

```
  i=1
  for X in `ls -1 *nc`
  do
       cdo merge $X temp.nc out.nc
       i=`expr $i+1`
       if [i!=500];  #This is the run so you want to keep out as your final output
       then 
           mv out.nc temp.nc ##### for use in future merges.  This will build up as $X nc files get merged to it.
  done
```