# merging multiple netcdf files into one netcdf file

Tags: variables, netcdf, nco, cdo-climate

I have three netcdf files with three different variables:

```
PRMSL.nc with variable PRMSL
UGRD.nc with variable UGRD
VGRD.nc with variable VGRD
```

These files have the same longitudinal and latitudinal coverage and resolution.  These files also have the same time steps.

How do I combine the above netcdf files into one big netcdf file with the variables PRMSL,VGRD,and UGRD?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [merging of Netcdf files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408587/merging-of-netcdf-files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cdo merge PRMSL.nc VGRD.nc UGRD.nc final.nc
```

where final.nc contains all the variables PRMSL,UGRD, and VGRD.